# RHEL7: Burning a DVD disc image

Tags: rhel

I'm trying to figure out how to burn a DVD iso image using RHEL7. When I pop a blank DVD+R into my DVDRW drive, it shows up as a blank disk on the Gnome desktop. However, Brasero do not recognize the drive. (I use this application with Debian/Kali and it works fine all of the time)

After Googling this for awhile, I found suggestions recommending mounting the disc, so I tried adding /dev/sr0 to my /etc/fstab, mounting it using the following options:

```
  /dev/sr0      /media/dvd      auto    rw,user,noauto,unhide 0 0
```

After doing this, and running the mount command, Brasero can now see the blank DVD. I was able to burn the DVD ISO image to my disc, but after Brasero finished burning the disc image, it seems to have hung up at around 75% completion for "creating image checksum".

Is there a better way to do all of this?  Should I be using a different tool now? Is there something better for Gnome? I feel like in 2018 burning a DVD ISO ought to be very straight forward in Linux...I must be completely missing something.

Update: Brasero actually did not burn anything to disk, though it did spin up the disk in the DVDRW drive. I was able to take that same disc to my Mac mini and burn a DVD ISO image on top of the disk, so it didn't actually do anything with the disc.

Comment: Why not just use a USB flash drive and the `dd` command?

Comment: Because I need to provide a DVD disc, not a thumb drive

Comment: Does whomever you're creating it for not have any USB ports? If they do them it doesn't make any difference as it's very rare today to install from DVD. If Brasero is stuck then you can disable the image checksum.

Comment: I certainly appreciate your work-around, and another easy solution is just to do this on a Mac or Windows PC. But since I could not get this to work with RHEL, I really want to understand how to do this. That Brasero doesn't see the blank dvd disc yet Gnome does seems to be indicative of something that is misconfigured on this RHEL workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out **growisofs** comes to the rescue. A couple of notes:

- **growisofs** doesn't like to be run as root or via sudo. So check the permissions on /dev/sr0 and make user your user account has the ability to work with the drive. For RHEL7 there is a "cdrom" group that the user account needs to be added to: "usermod -a -G cdrom [USER_ACCOUNT]"
- "dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/cdrom" can be used to verify you have a blank disc; look for "Disc status: blank" in the output.

To burn the disc, it is as easy as:

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/cdrom=/root/kali-linux-2017.3-amd64.iso
```

This tool can also be used with DVD+R discs and multi-session disc writes for DVD data discs. The man page is actually very good for this tool, so I recommend reading it to learn about the other options available.

Final Note: it looks like **cdrecord**/**wodim** is also an option, but after using **growisofs**, I didn't look into it any further.

Comment: And then don't forget to run "yum remove brasero"  :-)